# AngularJS - expandable textarea

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using an Angular directive, I'm trying to create a vertically expandable textarea that has the same number of rows as the number of '\n' characters in the text.

*(Note, I'm aware that this won't work for wrapping lines - I'll deal with this separately).*

```
app.directive('textExpand', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {

      RecalculateLines();

      function RecalculateLines() {
        scope.textEntry = "line1\nline2\n\nline3";
        angular.element(elem).attr("rows", (scope.textEntry).split("\n").length);
      }

      elem.on('keydown', function(event) {

        RecalculateLines();

      });
    }
  };
});
```

The idea is that I have a function to constantly recount the number of line breaks and dynamically update the number of rows using angular's jqLite to set the attribute. I call that function once in the beginning (to display any pre-existing values) and then once on every keystroke.

[See plunk here.](http://plnkr.co/edit/dsoHSgIbZxrcu7YwkGq3?p=preview)

`(scope.textEntry).split("\n").length` gets correctly counted when loading the hardcoded value and updated when typing into the box. However, setting it using .attr() only seems to work on the initial call and not on keystrokes.

What's weirder is that `.attr()` seems to work fine if passing it another number. See commented out code in the plunk where the box expands and shrinks fine based on a counter every keystroke.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were resetting the scope variable in the string that was checking it, moving this out of the function and adding `ng-trim="false"` fixes the problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/W0g1PupXYTUgiNLK1D8M?p=preview

```
  function RecalculateLines() {
    angular.element(elem).attr("rows", (scope.textEntry).split(/\r?\n/g).length);
    // angular.element(elem).attr("rows", rowCount);
  }
```

Comment: Paste and dragdrop do not trigger keydown. U may consider using ngModel.$viewChangeListener.push(RecalculateLines) instead.

Comment: ... knew it would be something I should have spotted >_> thanks for helping! @PetrAveryanov , I was thinking to have a separate handler for the paste event but will also consider what you suggested.